# jquery dialog box not working

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-ui, dialog

I have a jsp page. on clicking submit review a dialog box should come. Here is my all code snippets. 
JSP code :

```
<td align="left">
        <span>
        <div id="rate" class="rate" style="" title="Rate">Submit Review</div>
        </span>
        <div id="rateDialog" class="rateDialog" style="display:none;" title="Rating">
        <div id="showDialogMessage"></div>
        <label>Rate your overall satisfaction:</label>
         <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" class="star"/>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" class="star"/>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" class="star"/>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" class="star"/>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" class="star"/>
        <label>Please provide your review: </label>
        <textarea name="reviewArea" rows="5"></textarea>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" style="margin : 18px 0px 0px 93px;"/>

        </div>

        </td>
```

JS code :

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $(function() {
 $("#rateDialog").dialog({
 autoOpen: false,
 open: function( event, ui ) {
     $("#showDialogMessage").hide();
     $('#reviewArea').val('');
     }
 });
 $("#rate").on("click", function() {
 $("#rateDialog").dialog("open");
 });
 });
 // Validating Form Fields.....
 $("#submit").click(function(e) {
 $("#showDialogMessage").hide();
  var xmlhttp;
     $("#submit").prop('disabled',true);
     alert("called");
        var url="";
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {

            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                $("#submit").removeAttr('disabled');
                document.getElementById("showPasswordMessage").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                $("#showPasswordMessage").show();
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
 });
});
```

on clicking submit review it is showing this error. I am a beginner. any help will be greatly appreciated

```
Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you should do:

```
 // Instanciate the dialog
 var rateDialog = $("#rateDialog").dialog({
 autoOpen: false,
 open: function( event, ui ) {
     $("#showDialogMessage").hide();
     $('#reviewArea').val('');
     }
 });

 $("#rate").on("click", function() {
     // Display the dialog
     rateDialog.dialog("open");
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Sir! This problem is resolved. But i have stuck on another issue. I have a table. The dialog box is coming only for the first cell. If i click on submit review on the second row the dialog box is not coming :(

Comment: You're using `id="rate"` for each row, you have to use a class and change your code accordingly. Don't forget to set the answer as resolved.